# access python global variable in a nested function

Tags: python

I' am a beginner in python language. I've got a headache in understanding how global variables work. this is a specific example that doesn't make sense to me:

```
def func():
    def nested():
        global x
        x=1
    print(x)

func()
```

this throws :`global name 'x' is not defined`

Why is x is not available even though it has been made global in the nested function?

Comment: It's not really the global. `x` is only defined in a function you never call, but you try to print it. Try calling `nested()` before printing and the global will get defined.

Comment: yes. Because it isn't defined. Why do you *expect* it to be defined? `nested` is never called anywhere.

Comment: @MarkMeyer thank you. the global x inside a function won't define a variable outside unless it's called. I get it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to call `nested()` to define global variable `x`. ithout calling it, there is no definition of variable `x` and so you will have error!

```
def func():
    def nested():
        global x
        x=1
    nested()
    print(x)

func()
```